# Placing handlebar script inside div in ember

Tags: html, css, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to put handlebar scripts inside the left column, but I can't seem to put those inside the div. I must be doing this wrong--this question might be silly, but I am a beginner and have been struggling with it, so your answer would be much appreciated!

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
 <div class="container-fluid" id="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="left">

    <script type="text/x-handlebars"> 
      <p>Happening nearby..</p>
      <hr>
      {{outlet}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
      <p>{{eventName}}</p>
      <p>{{#link-to 'eventdetails'}}tell me about the details{{/link-to}}</p>
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specifically described the set up of your application, but I will use what you have posted to point you in the right direction.

1) You want the handlebars templates to be processed and inserted in tto the DOM by ember.

I am going to assume that the top level template that you posted is your application template. This must have an outlet within which content will be placed. Since you haven't named the first template you posted, I am going to assume that you would like it inline as part of your application template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
...
<div class="container-fluid" id="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="left">
        <p>Happening nearby..</p>
        <hr>
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
...
</script>
```

2) The second is what will be placed into the above outlet when you visit the index route. Also, if you are relying on Ember to populate your templates, you need to specifiy `data-template-name` not `id`.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <p>{{eventName}}</p>
  <p>{{#link-to 'eventdetails'}}tell me about the details{{/link-to}}</p>
</script>
```

3) Don't try to define handlebars templates nested within your HTML. I am not sure if you are doing this because you haven't posted the entirety of your HTML page, but each template needs to be defined seperately.

Comment: Thank you! I finally understand how to use outlets!